# Time Evolution of Coherent State (Gerry and Knight)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I'm stuck on some simple mathematics in finding the time evolved coherent state for a single-mode field from Gerry and Knight, Introductory Quantum Optics page 51.

The Hamiltonian is given by $\hat{H} = \hbar \omega \left(\hat{n} + \frac{1}{2}\right)$, and the time evolution is found as follows:

$$
\lvert \alpha, t \rangle \equiv \exp(-i\hat{H}t/\hbar) \lvert \alpha\rangle = e^{-i\omega t/2}e^{-i\omega t \hat{n}}\lvert\alpha\rangle = e^{-i\omega t/2}\lvert\alpha e^{-i\omega t}\rangle,
$$

however I do not understand this last step; why the term $e^{-i\omega t \hat{n}}$ can be brought into the ket like that as a phase change of the annihilation operator eigenvalue $\alpha$.

Here, $\hat{a} \lvert\alpha\rangle = \alpha \lvert\alpha\rangle$, and $\hat{n} = \hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
e^{-i\omega t/2}e^{-i\omega t \hat n}\vert\alpha\rangle&=
e^{-i\omega t/2}\sum_{N}e^{-i\omega t \hat n}e^{-\vert\alpha\vert^2/2}
\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\vert n\rangle\\
&=e^{-i\omega t/2}\sum_{N}e^{-\vert\alpha\vert^2/2}
\frac{e^{-i\omega nt}\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\vert n\rangle\\
&=e^{-i\omega t/2}\sum_{N}e^{-\vert\alpha\vert^2/2}
\frac{(e^{-i\omega t}\alpha)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\vert n\rangle\, ,\\
&=e^{-i\omega t/2}\vert e^{-i\omega t}\alpha\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! It hadn't occurred to me to use the definition in terms of the number states for some reason, I guess it was too obvious for the book to state

Comment: It's a classic.  If you don't "see" what to do you'll never get it.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like the book won't spell things out for you? Thankfully the lecture course doesn't require me to memorise this definition of the coherent state

Comment: It's a recurring exam or assignment question.  If you don't think of expanding in terms of number states you can spend hours trying to decompose the $e^{i\omega t \hat n}$ into some BCH-type factorization.

Comment: The answer above by ZeroTheHero is the correct way to do it, just be aware that a 1/2 term is missing in the exponential of the e term of the coherent state.

Comment: @alonoid fixed thanks.